# Android Multimedia service - simple question

Tags: java, android, multimedia

Is it possible to create an Android service that would listen in the background for Playback button (in the Android media player) clicks (something like onPlaybackListener) and then activate a GUI from which the current song can be controlled? i.e. stopped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot intercept the GUI events from other applications.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but it hasn't has to be an GUI event from other application. Can't it be a listener that listens if a song is played from the main media player app?

Comment: @user584513: Except that there are no such listeners. There is no concept in the Android OS or SDK of "the main media player app". What "the main media player app" is will vary by device. There are no requirements of "the main media player app" to send broadcasts around when the current song changes.